# postfix error sending mail to spam

Tags: php, smtp

I have a redmine instance sending emails using a GMail account and I realized that emails were being recognized as spam by gmail. Using postfix as relay, I could send email by console (using the 'mail' command), but redmine were still being flag as spam,

Here is my mail details

```
Delivered-To: abc@example.com
Received: by 10.114.29.166 with SMTP id l6csp194412ldh;
        Fri, 23 Nov 2012 03:10:39 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.58.162.130 with SMTP id ya2mr5620087veb.2.1353669038834;
        Fri, 23 Nov 2012 03:10:38 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <redmine@example.com>
Received: from domU-12-31-39-03-7D-77.compute-1.internal (ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com. [xxx.xx.xxx.xx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id y12si5657502vco.81.2012.11.23.03.10.38;
        Fri, 23 Nov 2012 03:10:38 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: xxx.xx.xxx.xx is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of redmine@example.com) client-ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: xxx.xx.xxx.xx is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of redmine@example.com) smtp.mail=redmine@example.com
Received: by domU-12-31-39-03-7D-77.compute-1.internal (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 3FDD638407; Fri, 23 Nov 2012 11:10:38 +0000 (UTC)
```

Comment: Is that all of the mail headers?  You have no `To`, `From`, etc.

Comment: Those are obviously just the transport headers.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your postfix. You need to setup `SPF`, `DKIM` and `reverse PTR` record for mail server `IP`. You can google on "How to setup SPF and DKIM".

I followed [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) by Jeff Atwood and understood all why its needed and how can I setup.

Comment: Amazon SES appears to offer this.